# Remove the Duplicate value item from 2 same format JSON objects in Java

Tags: java, json, string, duplicates

I'm looking for a way to remove the duplicate item from two JSON objects that both have the same value.
e.g.

First object:

```
{
 "a":true,
 "b":true,
 "c":true,
 "d":{"i":true,"ii":true,"iii":true}
}
```

Second object

```
{
 "a":false,
 "b":true,
 "c":true,
 "d":{"i":true,"ii":true,"iii":false}
}
```

And after removing the duplicate, I'd like to get

First object

```
{
 "a":true,
 "d":{"iii":true}
}
```

Second object

```
{
 "a":false,
 "d":{"iii":false}
}
```

I wonder if there's a tool already provides this function
(If that couldn't detect the duplicates inside the nested value, it's ok.)

Answer (score 0):

Found way myself, I convert the json to map and then compare to remove the duplicates. Then convert the reduced map back to json